# Were the aliens Al Bundy met in the Married with Children episode "Married... with Aliens", real?

Tags: aliens, married-with-children

In the *Married... with Children* episode called "Married... with Aliens", Al Bundy was paid a visit by a group of six little green aliens:

[image: Al Bundy on his couch, surrounded by six green aliens]

Apparently, these guys realized that:

> Al's smelly socks are the best spaceship fuel in the galaxy!

I was always wondering, **were these aliens real or a shoe-induced hallucination?**

Comment: Should have known! Only Loki would create a fake troll question for the lulz!

Comment: @Chloe Why fake? It's a legit question, based on a real episode and apparently it has a well defined answer. Care to elaborate why you think it's a troll question?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on the fact that Buck saw the aliens, it's safe to assume that they were indeed real.

> [Al looks at Buck.]
>
> **AL:** *What are you looking at? You know they were real, you were here. If you could talk you'd back me up, wouldn't ya?*
>
> **BUCK:** *Yeah, right. Mad men they lock up. Mad dogs they shoot.*
>
> <sub><sup>[MARRIED WITH ALIENS - FINAL DRAFT SCREENPLAY](http://www.albundy.net/marriedaniac/ate/script/0507fin.html)</sup></sub>

[image]

And if the aliens weren't real, then **where did Al's socks go?**

[image]

Comment: The socks disappear in the washing machine as everyone else's socks. It is impossible to retain an even number of socks from a washing machine. There is always at least one, but always an odd number, missing. But after examining a few washing machines, the most likely explanation is aliens. Who else could it be.

Comment: @Bent: insert obligatory meme of History Channel Guy ("I'm not saying it was aliens... but it was aliens!!!")